# How to see the retention for a particular topic in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, retention

I want to see the retention period set for a particular topic.
Is there any command?  I tried with

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper hostname:2181 --alter --config retention.ms=172800000 --topic <topic_name>
```

for deleting 2 days old data. But I want to see how many days are set in the retention period for all the topics.

Answer (score 73):

If you have altered a topic and want to view the topic configuration the following command will be helpful

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides
```

This will describe only the topics along with configurations that have configurations set that differ from the cluster defaults.

If you want to view the configurations for all topic
Either you can view these properties **`log.retention.hours`** or **`log.retention.ms`** in `server.properties` in kafka config directory.

Answer (score 15):

See config 'log.retention.hours' in [Kafka Doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs):

> The number of hours to keep a log file before deleting it (in hours), tertiary to log.retention.ms property

Default value is 168 hours which is 7 days.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative ways:

1. use call sh-command through a container

```sh
docker run --rm -it confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest sh -c "kafka-topics --zookeeper 11.22.33.44:5555 --describe --topic topic-name"
```

[image]

2. use [Kafka Tool](http://www.kafkatool.com/)

[image]

---

Take into account that it would be displayed just params different from [default values](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html).

At the example above, the *retention.ms* is *14 days*, when default one is *7 days*.

Answer (score 2):

Simply the below command will help

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server server_ip:9092 --describe --topic topic_name
```

Along with other infos , it will print delete.retention.ms.

A sample output will be

```
Topic:TOPIC NAME    PartitionCount:6    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:compression.type=gzip,segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=100,max.message.bytes=100001200,delete.retention.ms=100000

Topic: TOPIC NAME   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
Topic: TOPIC NAME   Partition: 1    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3 Isr: 3
Topic: TOPIC NAME   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
Topic: TOPIC NAME   Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
Topic: TOPIC NAME   Partition: 4    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3 Isr: 3
Topic: TOPIC NAME   Partition: 5    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

Comment: This command return only topic details, we are not getting a retention period of the topic.

Comment: actually there is at the top of the columns

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `retention.ms` or `retention.bytes` or any other config for any topic, you can simply use this command:

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server <BOOTSTRAP_SERVER> --describe --topic <TOPIC_NAME> --all
```

Make sure to put here the address of the broker and the desired topic. This will output all configs defined for a particular topic, including the retention. Hope it helped :)