# For how long data is stored in kafka server?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose i am sending some messages from kafka producer to kafka consumer then where it will store? Is there any databases for storing messages ? And for how long messages are store?

Can anyone please explain it.

Comment: http://www.allprogrammingtutorials.com/tutorials/configuring-messages-retention-time-in-kafka.php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135820/how-to-see-the-retention-for-a-particular-topic-in-kafka

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Data is produced/consumed to/from Kafka topics. A *Topic* is the core abstraction that Kafka provides for a stream of records. A topic is similar to a table in a typical database.

If you want to move the data from Kafka into a database (or vice versa) you can use Confluent's bundled connectors which can [import and export data from some of the most commonly used data systems.](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connectors.html)

Regarding the period you can keep data in topics, you need to look for the retention policy and period.

> The Kafka cluster durably persists all published records—whether or
>   not they have been consumed—using a configurable retention period. For
>   example, if the retention policy is set to two days, then for the two
>   days after a record is published, it is available for consumption,
>   after which it will be discarded to free up space.

Retention period is a configurable parameter that allows you to store the data for as long as you like. For example if you configure the following parameters;

```
log.retention.minutes=3
log.cleanup.policy=delete
```

a message will remain to the topic for 3 minutes. For more details regarding these parameters, have a look at the [broker configuration parameters](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) where you can also find information for some more parameters related to topic retention (such as `log.retention.bytes`, `log.segment.bytes`, `log.retention.check.interval`, `log.roll.ms` etc).

My advice for you would be to start with the introductory material which can be found in the [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/intro) in order to be able to understand how Kafka works in general

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning about RocksDB on the Kafka Streams side. I believe that's what OP refers to as database