# Is there a way to describe a topic configuration with node-rdkafka?

Tags: node.js, librdkafka

I use an apache kafka cluster and I consume message on this topic using node-rdkafka (wrapper of the native librdkafka library).

I want to retrieve the retention time period of this topic for some performance issues for another part of my code unrelated to kafka.

It is pretty simple in console : [How to see the retention for a particular topic in kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135820/how-to-see-the-retention-for-a-particular-topic-in-kafka) but I did not find any way to get it using the `node-rdkafka` and it's not possible for me to change this library.

On `node-rdkafka`, even the `Kafka.AdminClient` only allow to createTopic/deleteTopic/createPartitions (checked on the doc here : https://blizzard.github.io/node-rdkafka/current/AdminClient.html)

Is there a way to achieve one way or another ?